# Getting file header corrupt error while trying to process each individual file types in parallel within zip file

Tags: c#, async-await, concurrency, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I have a zip file available in azure blob storage which contains 2 types of files, A & B.

I need to read file from azure blob storage and process each of file in parallel.

I am trying here most efficient way read and process the file as well.

For below code randomly I am getting error for couple of file (say in Zip I have 10 files, 3 processed successfully, 7 failing with error `A local file header is corrupt`)

Please suggest what the problem when I am trying to send `IEnumerable<ZipArchiveEntry>` on multiple `Task.Run`? How can I make sure both file type process go in parallel?

```
    private static async Task DownloadFromStream(BlobClient blobClient)
    {
        using var archive = new ZipArchive(await blobClient.OpenReadAsync(
            new BlobOpenReadOptions(false)));

        //get different file types
        var typeAFiles = GetFiles(archive, "TYPE_A");
        var typeBFiles= GetFiles(archive, "TYPE_B");

        //trying to process each type file in parallel
        var fileProcessTasks = new List<Task>
            {
                Task.Run(async () => await ProcessData(typeAFiles)),
                Task.Run(async () => await ProcessData(typeBFiles))
            };

        await Task.WhenAll(fileProcessTasks);
    }

    private static async Task ProcessData(IEnumerable<ZipArchiveEntry> files)
    {
        foreach (var entry in files)
        {
            try
            {
                var content = await new System.IO.StreamReader(entry.Open(),
                    Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEndAsync();
                //Console.WriteLine(content.Length);
                // processing Logic here
                Console.WriteLine("*************");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<ZipArchiveEntry> GetFiles(ZipArchive archive,
        string fileType)
    {
        return archive.Entries.Where(y => y.Name.StartsWith(fileType));
    }
```

**Note: If I am using code like below, then all files processing successful and never getting any error,**

```
var tasks = new List<Func<Task>>
        {
            await ProcessData(typeAFiles),
            await ProcessData(typeBFiles)
        };
        
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks.AsParallel().Select(async task => await task()));
```

Comment: Does the line `Console.WriteLine(content.Length);` represents the processing of a file? Would you be satisfied with a solution that would parallelize just the processing, and not the reading from the `ZipArchive`?

Comment: thanks @TheodorZoulias for your comment. Console.WriteLine(content.Length) just for checking the content length, but after that real processing logic I have. I realize this as well that content reading is not parallelize. Could you tell how I can do both content reading and processing parallelize?

Comment: I am not familiar with the `ZipArchive` class. My assumption is that most likely it's not thread-safe, in which case it could not be used by multiple threads at the same time.

Comment: Are you trying to read the blob while it is still being written to? This would be a definite reason for this error.

Comment: @Kit, file is fully written and then only I am reading.

Answer (score 4):

This error can occur when you are opening the `ZipArchive` whether in parallel or not if the archive has not been fully written to (i.e. still open). The zip file must be closed and complete.

You can also check to see if the header has a bad hash. That will throw off read accesses, again, whether parallel or not.

Also, noting your `GetFiles()` method, it has deferred execution. You may fare better by `ToList()`ing it (i.e. make it eagerly execute before passing to your parallel tasks).

Comment: Thanks @Kit for your reply. The file is fully written. Will eagerly execution (`ToList()`) slow down the performance here. I have big size ZIP file having 1K files. Please check my `note` above where I just wrote code in different way and NO error.